# grouping row with sum conditions SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, metabase

I try to transform this table:

| NB Travel | NB User |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 25 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 5 | 16 |
| 6 | 25 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 16 |
| 9 | 25 |
| 10 | 3 |

to this table:

| NB Travel | NB User |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2-5 | 20+25+12+16 |
| 5-10 | 16+25+5+16+25+3 |

This is for graphique representation with grouping data like this.

I have try with this:

```
SELECT

SUM(CASE WHEN source2."Nb Trip" = 1 then source2."nb User" ELSE 0 END) as "1",
SUM(CASE WHEN source2."Nb Trip" = 2 or  source2."Nb Trip" = 3 or  source2."Nb Trip" = 4 or  source2."Nb Trip" = 5  then source2."nb User" ELSE 0 END) as "2-5",
SUM(CASE WHEN source2."Nb Trip" = 5 or  source2."Nb Trip" = 6 or  source2."Nb Trip" = 7 or  source2."Nb Trip" = 8 or  source2."Nb Trip" = 9 or  source2."Nb Trip" = 10 then source2."nb User" ELSE 0 END) as "5-10"

FROM

(
SELECT count(*) AS "nb User", "source"."Nb Trip" AS "Nb Trip"
FROM 
(SELECT "public"."Wesk_Trip"."userId" AS "userId", count(*) AS "Nb Trip" FROM "public"."Wesk_Trip"
GROUP BY "public"."Wesk_Trip"."userId")"source"

GROUP BY "source"."Nb Trip" ORDER BY "source"."Nb Trip" ASC
) as source2
```

| 1 | 2-5 | 5-10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 73 | 90 |

Anyone have an idea to help me?
thank you in advance

Comment: Is `NB Travel=5` duplicate in your results?

Comment: yes i know but i need to group data like this

Comment: use: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f5084031921e53535b71b40dae2c092)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   `NB Travel`,
   `NB User`
FROM tbl WHERE `NB Travel`=1

UNION ALL

SELECT
   CONCAT(MIN(`NB Travel`),'-',MAX(`NB Travel`)),
   GROUP_CONCAT(`NB User` SEPARATOR '+')
FROM tbl WHERE `NB Travel` BETWEEN 2 AND 5

UNION ALL

SELECT
   CONCAT(MIN(`NB Travel`),'-',MAX(`NB Travel`)),
   GROUP_CONCAT(`NB User` SEPARATOR '+')
FROM tbl WHERE `NB Travel` BETWEEN 5 AND 10
```

output:

| NB Travel | NB User |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2-5 | 20+25+12+16 |
| 5-10 | 16+25+5+16+25+3 |

EDIT: Or should I have said: use [FBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5decb36b2d1c6eeed767be26e56b0a41) ?